# react-native-share on iOS get cannot read property 'FACEBOOK' of undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, share

I get this error in iOS simulator when I started using `react-native-share`

[image]

```
cannot read property 'FACEBOOK' of undefined
RNShare
index.js:208:36
...
```

after run 
`npm install`
I run `cd ios/ && pod install`

this is a `package.json` part

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.2.2",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.4.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "8.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-share": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
```

and this is a Podfile part

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'mobile' do

  ...

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  ...

  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'
```

Comment: Check this thread https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using RN version `0.61` you don't have to manually add `RNShare` in podfile.

1. Remove `pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'` from pod file
2. Delete `pods` folder and podlock file inside ios folder
3. Run `pod install` again

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share#automatic-way